# Convert JSON object array value to string array in VB.NET without loop

Tags: json, vb.net, linq

I've a JSON object array like this

```
dim d as string="[{name:'alex',age:20,id:1},{name:'John',age:22,id:2},
{name:'Philip',age:26,id:3},{name:'Mathew',age:27,id:4},
{name:'James',age:30,id:5},{name:'Antony',age:20,id:6},
{name:'Kevin',age:10,id:7}]"
```

I parsed the JSON string array using JSON serializer as this way.

```
DIM mj() as mysample
dim js as new javascriptserializer
mj=js.deserialize(Of mysample)(d)
```

But my requirement is to convert one attribute value of that json object to a string array based on a condition. For example the result array should contain all **name** with **age** 20.

```
The array should be   ['Antony','Alex']
```

How can we achieve this without any loop. I mean some solution using LINQ

Comment: JSON is not just a string with a fancy format - it is the result of serialization.  The string you created is not valid json.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class with the properties found in you json, then use a library like newtonsoft to serielize your json to a list of object using your new class

```
    public class Person{

    public string name {get;set;}
    public string age {get;set;}


}

List<Person> personList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(jsonString);
```

Then use this list to run a linq to find the ones with age = 20

```
List<string> result = from personList.select(new {age = age}).where(p => p.age == 20)
```

This code is not tested just to provide a guide to the result.